# Hacerle un Downgrade a PHP de 5.4 a 5.3 en Centos 6.9

Tags: php, centos

Hace poco necesitamos actualizar la versión de `mysql` y al instalar los repos y proceder a la instalación de `mysql` estos repos me actualizaron a su vez el servidor `php` afectando la funcionalidad del sistema que tenemos corriendo. Después de actuar con normalidad ahora arroja este error:

> Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in
>   /ubicacion/de/carpetaraiz Linea de codigo####

Por lo que estamos en la necesidad de hacerle un downgrade a la versión que anteriormente estaba corriendo. Si alguien puede darme una mano y orientarme de como hacerlo, estaría infinitamente agradecido.

Comment: Si pudiera darte un beso lo haría.

Comment: Me equivoqué en mi comentario anterior y lo expliqué al revés, te dejo una respuesta más completa. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error indicado es debido a una de las incompativilidades de las versiones 5.3 y 5.4, se puede ver una lista [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/migration54.incompatible.php), en concreto la incompatibilidad es:

> El paso por referencia en tiempo de llamada ha sido eliminado.

En la documentación de [paso por referencia](http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php) encontramos una nota que no indica lo siguiente:

> Nota: No existe ningún signo de referencia en una llamada a una función - sólo en la definición de la función. Las definiciones de funciones por sí solas son suficientes para pasar correctamente el argumento por referencia. A partir de PHP 5.3.0, se obtendrá una advertencia diciendo que "call-time pass-by-reference" (pasar por referencia en tiempo de llamada) está obsoleto cuando se use & en foo(&$a);. A partir de PHP 5.4.0, el paso por referencia en tiempo de llamada ha sido eliminado, por lo que su uso emitirá un error fatal.

Resumiendo esto quiere decir que las llamadas a funciones pasando variable como referencia esta obsoleto, en PHP 5.3 se emitia una advertencia y en 5.4 un error fatal. Ejemplo:

```
<?php
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$var = 1;

foo(&$var); // ERROR

foo($var); // Correcto
```

Tambien en la documentacion podemos ver que solo se pueden pasar lo siguiente por referencia:

- Variables, esto es, foo($a)
- Nuevas declaraciones, esto es, foo(new foobar())
- Referencias devueltas desde funciones

---

Si sólamente este es el error que has tenido al migrar de PHP 5.3.x a PHP 5.4.x, mi recomendación es que corrijas el código quitando las referencias, es decir eliminando los & (ampersand o et) antepuestos a las variables en las funciones.